# Document will not update and does not return error. Corrupt?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

One particular document will not update, while this same query updates any other _id which I query:

```
Category.findOneAndUpdate(
    {_id : req.params.id},
    {parent : req.body.parent},
    function(err,obj){
        console.log(err,obj)
        if(err) 
            res.status(500).send(err);
        else
            res.send(200);
    }
)
```

The callback does not return an error. It's the same behavior as success or document not found.

Also, when I run a simple `.find({_id:id})` it finds the document, but updates to that same id   don't work.

Comment: Does it work doing the same query in the mongo CLI?

Comment: It does but thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

try adding the following code to monitor errors

```
connection.on("error", function(err){
  console.dir(err);
});
```

also, look here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#safe